# azuread login issues with azure virtual desktop

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, virtual, desktop

I am trying to explore the azure virtual desktop with azuread joined in it (not azure AD DS).
here are the steps I have followed

1. created virtual desktop pool with one windows 10 vm in it.
2. granted virtual machine user login , desktop virtualization user role assigned to the workspace and application group.
3. I have also assigned this vm to my user in hostpool assig option.
4. from bastion host, I can see from about pc This vm is joined to AzureAD.
5. when I try to login from following link, (cred passed are Username- AzureAD\username@domain.com password-working password) I am getting this error "Oops, we couldn't connect to "SessionDesktop"
   Sign in failed. Please check your username and password and try again."
   https://rdweb.wvd.microsoft.com/arm/webclient/index.html
6. we have conditional access MFA is enabled.

I have gone through multiple documents, various troubleshooting forums , but still not getting any solution. can you please advise what I should check to make this work.

thanks in advance.

Comment: username@domain.com try in that way.

Comment: make sure from username you are trying to access is added in your Hostpool->Assignement.

Comment: thanks for reply, I tried azuread\username@domain.com , AzureAD\username@domain.com and username@domain.com as well. but no luck. its still failing....      in Hostpool Assignment I have assigned my username to this vm already.  ... none of the option is working.

Comment: Give Some Member permission to your user from you are signing. In you VM Active Directory -> Active Directory Users and Computers->Users-> Select User from your siging-> Properties ->Member of -> Add->

Comment: Enterprise Admin,Administrators,Domain Admin,Domain Users,Group Policy Creation,Schema Admin

Comment: @kandardp did your problem got resolved ?

Comment: thanks @RahulKumarShaw-MT for providing solutions. I have tried above solutions. but it dint work. so we have removed windows VM sign-in from the CA policy and now I am able to login to VM with my AAD login. thanks again..

Comment: Can you please post this as answer so it can help other community member who may encounter the same problem.

Comment: sure @RahulKumarShaw-MT  , I have tried this one.  below link there is a line  "for now, you can exclude MFA requirement by configuring Conditional Access policy that excludes  **"Azure Windows VM Sign-In"** app from the list of cloud apps that require MFA. To learn more about Windows Hello for Business, see"                                https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You [kandarp sarvaiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14132598/kandarp-sarvaiya) for sharing your suggestion. Based on your comment posting this as an answer to help other community member.

Removed windows VM sign-in from the Condition Access policy and now able to login to VM with my AAD login.

Note : you can exclude MFA requirement by configuring Conditional Access policy that excludes "**Azure Windows VM Sign-In**" app from the list of cloud apps that require MFA.

Refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows) for more information.